# Find "gap" and split the data

Tags: list-manipulation

For example I have a ordered list

```
l=Sort@Join[Range[-10,10,0.01],Range[-20,-15,0.05],Range[20,23,0.2]]
```

And I want to split the data according to the "apparent" large gaps in data, so the expected output would be

```
{Range[-20,-15,0.05],Range[-10,10,0.01],Range[20,23,0.2]}
```

Example of real data

> 

```
{2.06764, -2.06764, -2.06757, 2.06757, -2.06745, 2.06745, -2.06728, \
2.06728, -2.06707, 2.06707, 2.06681, -2.06681, -2.0665, 2.0665, \
-2.06615, 2.06615, -2.06576, 2.06576, -2.06533, 2.06533, -2.06486, \
2.06486, -2.06436, 2.06436, -2.06382, 2.06382, -2.06325, 2.06325, \
2.06265, -2.06265, 2.06203, -2.06203, -2.06138, 2.06138, -2.06072, \
2.06072, -2.06004, 2.06004, -2.05935, 2.05935, -2.05866, 2.05866, \
2.05796, -2.05796, 2.05726, -2.05726, -2.05656, 2.05656, -2.05588, \
2.05588, -2.05522, 2.05522, -2.05457, 2.05457, -2.05395, 2.05395, \
-2.05335, 2.05335, -2.05279, 2.05279, -2.05227, 2.05227, -2.05179, \
2.05179, -2.05136, 2.05136, -2.05097, 2.05097, -2.05064, 2.05064, \
2.05037, -2.05037, -2.05015, 2.05015, 2.05, -2.05, 2.0499, -2.0499, \
1.77731, -1.77731, -1.77731, 1.77731, -1.75793, 1.75793, 1.75748, \
-1.75748, 1.75675, -1.75675, 1.75572, -1.75572, 1.75442, -1.75442, \
-1.75283, 1.75283, -1.75098, 1.75098, 1.74887, -1.74887, -1.74649, \
1.74649, 1.74387, -1.74387, -1.74101, 1.74101, -1.73792, 1.73792, \
1.7346, -1.7346, -1.73106, 1.73106, -1.72731, 1.72731, 1.72336, \
-1.72336, 1.71922, -1.71922, 1.71488, -1.71488, 1.71037, -1.71037, \
1.70568, -1.70568, 1.70084, -1.70084, -1.69584, 1.69584, 1.69071, \
-1.69071, 1.68544, -1.68544, 1.68007, -1.68007, -1.67459, 1.67459, \
-1.66903, 1.66903, -1.66342, 1.66342, 1.65777, -1.65777, 1.65213, \
-1.65213, -1.64654, 1.64654, -1.64105, 1.64105, -1.63574, 1.63574, \
-1.63071, 1.63071, -1.62606, 1.62606, 1.62194, -1.62194, -1.61852, \
1.61852, -1.61594, 1.61594, 1.61435, -1.61435, 1.52612, -1.52612, \
1.52389, -1.52389, 1.52036, -1.52036, 1.51572, -1.51572, -1.51019, \
1.51019, 1.50394, -1.50394, -1.49711, 1.49711, -1.48981, 1.48981, \
1.48213, -1.48213, 1.47412, -1.47412, 1.46583, -1.46583, 1.4573, \
-1.4573, -1.44856, 1.44856, 1.43963, -1.43963, 1.43052, -1.43052, \
1.42125, -1.42125, -1.41183, 1.41183, 1.40227, -1.40227, -1.39258, \
1.39258, 1.38277, -1.38277, 1.37284, -1.37284, 1.36279, -1.36279, \
-1.35264, 1.35264, -1.34239, 1.34239, 1.33204, -1.33204, -1.32159, \
1.32159, -1.31105, 1.31105, -1.30043, 1.30043, 1.28973, -1.28973, \
1.27895, -1.27895, -1.2681, 1.2681, 1.25719, -1.25719, 1.24623, \
-1.24623, 1.23523, -1.23523, 1.22422, -1.22422, -1.21325, 1.21325, \
-1.20242, 1.20242, -1.192, 1.192, 1.18287, -1.18287, -1.1521, 1.1521, \
-1.15034, 1.15034, -1.13894, 1.13894, -1.12824, 1.12824, -1.117, \
1.117, 1.1055, -1.1055, -1.09384, 1.09384, -1.08208, 1.08208, \
1.07025, -1.07025, -1.05835, 1.05835, -1.04641, 1.04641, 1.03443, \
-1.03443, -1.02242, 1.02242, -1.0104, 1.0104, 0.998357, -0.998357, \
-0.986315, 0.986315, -0.974278, 0.974278, 0.962258, -0.962258, \
0.950264, -0.950264, -0.938309, 0.938309, 0.926406, -0.926406, \
0.91457, -0.91457, 0.90282, -0.90282, -0.891177, 0.891177, 0.879662, \
-0.879662, 0.868305, -0.868305, -0.857136, 0.857136, -0.846195, \
0.846195, 0.835525, -0.835525, -0.825179, 0.825179, -0.815217, \
0.815217, 0.805711, -0.805711, -0.796745, 0.796745, -0.788415, \
0.788415, -0.780827, 0.780827, -0.7741, 0.7741, -0.768358, 0.768358, \
-0.763727, 0.763727, 0.760322, -0.760322, -0.758237, 0.758237, \
-0.558185, 0.558185, -0.558185, 0.558185, -0.460503, 0.460503, \
-0.458199, 0.458199, -0.454443, 0.454443, -0.449346, 0.449346, \
-0.443042, 0.443042, -0.435671, 0.435671, -0.427369, 0.427369, \
0.418261, -0.418261, -0.40846, 0.40846, -0.398063, 0.398063, \
-0.387154, 0.387154, -0.375805, 0.375805, -0.364074, 0.364074, \
-0.352014, 0.352014, 0.339668, -0.339668, 0.32707, -0.32707, \
-0.314254, 0.314254, -0.301244, 0.301244, -0.288065, 0.288065, \
-0.274734, 0.274734, -0.26127, 0.26127, 0.247687, -0.247687, \
0.233997, -0.233997, -0.220213, 0.220213, -0.206345, 0.206345, \
-0.192401, 0.192401, -0.178389, 0.178389, -0.164318, 0.164318, \
-0.150193, 0.150193, -0.136022, 0.136022, -0.121809, 0.121809, \
-0.107559, 0.107559, 0.0932789, -0.0932789, 0.0789718, -0.0789718, \
-0.0646427, 0.0646427, -0.0502958, 0.0502958, 0.0359351, -0.0359351, \
-0.0215646, 0.0215646, -0.00718727, 0.00718727}
```

```

Comment: `ClusteringComponents[l, 3]` or `FindClusters[l,3]`

Comment: @DavidG.Stork Thanks for the suggestion. I tried this on my real data but it requires my input of the number of "components" to get the correct result, and they split the positive and negative segments but they are not gapped. Is there a way to avoid this? or better, a way to get it without specifying the number ofcomponents?

Comment: Can you share your real data? The structure in the data might suggest a more effective approach. Otherwise look at `SplitBy` with an appropriate Difference function.

Comment: @MarcoB I think you mean `Split` rather than `SplitBy` : `SplitBy` doesn't permit to compare two successive elements.

Comment: For what it's worth, `ClusteringComponents[l]` finds 3 clusters.

Comment: @andre314 I sure did! Thank you for pointing that out.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
splitList=Split[l, #2-#1<=1&];(* 1 arbitrary chosen *)

splitList[[1]]==Range[-20,-15,0.05]
splitList[[2]]==Range[-10,10,0.01]
splitList[[3]]==Range[20,23,0.2]


(* True
   True
   True *)
```

See the example "Split at jumps" in [`Split`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Split.html)-> `Generalizations and Extensions` for a better explanation.